# Executing C functions from C++ file results in linker error: "conflicting declaration with 'C' linkage" and "previous declaration 'C++' linkage

Tags: c++, arduino, linker, linker-errors

I am attempting to execute a C function from within a C++ file in the Arduino framework. The function I am trying to run, `GuiLib_ShowScreen`, appears in `GuiLib.h` and `GuiLib.c` as follows (the files are massive so for convenience and relevance sake I included only definitions):

```cpp
extern void GuiLib_ShowScreen(
      const GuiConst_INT16U StructureNdx,
      GuiConst_INT16S CursorFieldToShow,
      GuiConst_INT8U ResetAutoRedraw)
  { ... }
```

And the file from which I am trying to include `GuiLib_ShowScreen`:

```cpp
#ifndef _DISPLAY_DRIVER_H_
#define _DISPLAY_DRIVER_H_

#include <TFT_eSPI.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <ac.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "gui/GuiLib.h"

#define USE_DMAA_TO_TFT

extern "C"
{
    void GuiLib_ShowScreen(const GuiConst_INT16U StructureNdx, GuiConst_INT16S CursorFieldToShow, GuiConst_INT8U ResetAutoRedraw);
}

class display_
{
public:
    TFT_eSPI tft;
    bool getStatus();
    void initPWM();
    void writePWM(int duty);
};

#endif
```

And my main.cpp:

```cpp
#include "display_driver.h"

void TaskPushDMA(void *pvParameters)
{
  while (true)
  {
    GuiLib_ShowScreen(GuiStruct_main_0, GuiLib_NO_CURSOR, GuiLib_RESET_AUTO_REDRAW);
    vTaskDelay(1000);
  }
}
```

My issue is when compiling, I get a linker error that looks like this:

```
In file included from src\main.cpp:6:0:
src/display_driver.h:14:129: error: conflicting declaration of 'void GuiLib_ShowScreen(short unsigned int, short int, unsigned char)' with 'C' linkage
     void GuiLib_ShowScreen(const GuiConst_INT16U StructureNdx, GuiConst_INT16S CursorFieldToShow, GuiConst_INT8U ResetAutoRedraw);
                                                                                                                                 ^
In file included from src/display_driver.h:8:0,
                 from src\main.cpp:6:
src/gui/GuiLib.h:1847:13: note: previous declaration with 'C++' linkage
 extern void GuiLib_ShowScreen(
             ^
```

From what I am getting from this, is it seems to be suggesting that the original linkage is C++, which is strange considering the definition is in a C file. I've read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage) as well as previously opened issues here yet no luck. I also attempted creating a conditional like such:

```cpp
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" int foo(int, int); // C++ compiler sees this
#else
int foo(int, int);            // C compiler sees this
#endif
```

Comment: Does GuiLib.h put anything in an `extern "C"` section? If not, you probably need to wrap the `#include "GuiLib.h"` within an `extern "C"` section. Also confirm that the Arduino IDE is actually compiling the .c files as C and not as C++.

Comment: By the way, the "conflicting declaration" error looks like it has been emitted by the compiler, not the linker.

Comment: You do not need to tag C, since this is not really a C question. Although it involves C code, it will not involve C rules (unless something arises not currently stated in the problem). The issue is a matter of C++ syntax and rules, even when it is C++ code invoking routines defined in C.

Comment: Re “which is strange considering the definition is in a C file”: When the C++ compiler processing `#include <gui/GuiLib.h>`, it does not know that header file declares routines that are defined in C files. It simply includes the contents of the header in its compilation as if they had appeared directly in the C++ file. It processes them using C++ rules. To tell the compiler they have C linkage, you need to use `extern "C" { … }`.

Comment: If you cannot wrap the entire header in that, as with `extern "C" {` / `#include <gui/GuiLib.h>` / `}`, because something in the header conflicts with that, then it may suffice to declare `GuiLib_ShowScreen` inside `extern "C"` **before** including the header. That will tell the compiler it has `C` linkage so it knows that before seeing the declaration inside the header.

Comment: @IanAbbott It puts nothing in `extern "C"`, however it uses `extern` on what seems like every single function. I am using platform io and it should be compiling it as C. My mistake on the error, I had another one prior and mismatched them when making this post. In this case it is a compiler error.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you for the response. When I place `#include <gui/GuiLib.h>` within the scope of `extern "C" { ... }` I receive a massive linking error that looks like: `In function `DrawStructure':` followed by an `undefined reference to `GetItemByte'` to many of its members. There's at least 20 lines of this and it's too long to post here.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I thought it was a great solution to place `GuiLib_ShowScreen` before `#include <gui/GuiLib.h>` but to my suspicion, it didn't compile due to not recognizing the parameters of `GuiLib_ShowScreen`. I tried changing them to`uint16_t` format but got a conflicting declaration error due to mismatched parameters between them.

Comment: That seems like progress. Now you need to work out where `GetItemByte` is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying suggestions from the comments, this cleared out the error. I included the library outside the scope after `extern "C"` and changed the parameters of `GuiLib_ShowScreen()` to their native types, defined in the library as `#define GuiConst_INT16U  unsigned short`. There was a compatibility issue placing the include statement within the scope, and because my original error stated `previous declaration with 'C++' linkage` it seems apparent that the include statement was interpreted automatically as a C++ header instead of C.

```cpp
extern "C"
{
    void GuiLib_ShowScreen(unsigned short StructureNdx, signed short CursorFieldToShow, unsigned char ResetAutoRedraw);
}

#include "gui/GuiLib.h"
```